# Sequential animations in javascript/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a circle, consisting of 12 arc segments and I want to allow the user to see the transition from the start pattern to the end pattern. (there will be many start and end patterns).

I have included the transition property in the css file, so that is not the issue.

Here is my code so far:

```
function playAnimations(){
console.log("gets inside playanimations")
var totalLength = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].children.length
console.log(totalLength)
for(var i = 0; i < totalLength; i++){
    var current_pattern = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].children[i]
        for(var j = 0; j < 12; j++){
            $('#LED' + (j+1) ).css('transition-duration', '0s');
            $('#LED' + (j+1) ).css({fill: current_pattern.children[1].children[j].style.backgroundColor});

        }

        for(var k = 0; k < 12; k++){
            $('#LED' + (k+1) ).css('transition-duration', "" + current_pattern.children[3].children[0].value + "ms");
            $('#LED' + (k+1) ).css({fill: current_pattern.children[2].children[k].style.backgroundColor});

        }    

}
}
```

The outer for loop traverses through all the patterns while the inner two for loops traverse through the start and end values for that particular pattern. The problem I am having is that I only see the end colors on the circle and not the start colors.

Does anyone know a good workaround or what I could possibly do to rectify this issue? Any feedback or help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that youre not letting any time to transition, you set one color and immediately sets the next. You need to use setTimeout before setting the next color. IF you put up a jsfiddle with your so far working code it will be easier to formulate an answer.

Comment: The code you provided is all but a [mcve]. By just adding the minimal HTML and CSS you'd probably get quicker and more reliable answers.

Comment: So if you found the answer, http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your Elements a `transition-delay` value. Of course a different one for each, like this

```
#LED1 {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

#LED2 {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

...

#LED2 {
    transition-delay: 1.2s;
}
```

That should do it. You should be able to set the `transition-duration` directly in the **CSS** as well, no need for JavaScript I think.

Is there a special reason to have 2 inner for loops? Shouldn't one doing both be sufficient?

Comment: I have a set of start values and end values. What I basically want to achieve is have the circle display the start values (they are just a bunch of colors) and then transition to the end value colors. So I thought one loop for each set of values was the right idea. How do you do this with one loop?

Comment: Unfortunately transition-delay did not work, it still only displays the colors after the second inner for loop has run.

Comment: The problem is, that this code probably runs so fast, that the visible effect will be the same as if all those 4 commands were written in one for loop. You want to at least use `setTimeout` for the second loop. Also I noticed you're using `fill`, isn't that for SVGs?

Comment: When I use a setTimeout for the second for loop, it works for only one pattern. However, when I add more patterns, the circle only displays the animation for the very last pattern

Comment: Probably the same thing. Each iteration of your outer for loop runs so fast, you won't be able to see it. So you might wanna try a setTimeout as well for the whole for loop content. This probably is not a beautiful solution though. Also keep in mind, that setTimeout is asynchronous.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the transition properties you need to define

   ```
   transition-property*
   transition-duration*
   transition-timing-function
   transition-delay
   ```

   transition-delay could help you to concatenate transitions if you set it using a js loop.
2. Check your function is getting and setting the right values (a quick check in chrome's dev console will help you)
3. Are you sure you want to get elements by **container** as class? As it's a common name for divs, you may be getting some unwanted elements in your function. I'd recommend changing the class to another less common name.
4. Why two loops? I imagine the first one is for resetting the colors before the actual transition as you define `transition-duration:0s;` The second one would be the actual transition?.
5. The problem I see in each loop is you set css in two lines (separated with a ;). 
   Try `$('#LED' + (k+1) ).css('transition-duration', "" + current_pattern.children[3].children[0].value + "ms").css({fill: current_pattern.children[2].children[k].style.backgroundColor});`.

   And maybe changing fill to background-color

   `$('#LED' + (k+1) ).css('transition-duration', "" + current_pattern.children[3].children[0].value + "ms").css('background-color', current_pattern.children[2].children[k].style.backgroundColor);`

You can find all the docs about transitions at [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)!

Comment: I had the transition property in my CSS

Comment: There's no way I would have known that, so why downvote me?

Comment: I didn't down vote you, just upvoted so you went back to 0.

Comment: ;) ok, back to your problem. 

what is the value of current_pattern.children[3].children[0] ?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity - I didn't include my css or any of the other code just for the sake of simplicity. current_pattern.children[3].children[0] .value is what I use to grab data from a text field so that the user can specify the transition duration

Comment: @CamiloWaitforit did you knew that w3s(omething) has nothing to do with W3C? I'm just scared to see a go see here's a W3S link when there's loads of proper and reliable documentation on the net.and you could at least write one line of code. (BTW they even sell laughable and irrelevant *certificates*)

Comment: I did not and I don't think that fact is relevant, I'm not promoting the website nor recommending it as a place to get certificates from. Thanks for the information though, I see now W3C is the proper documentation to go to, ill edit my answer ;)